# Permission Denial: receiving Intent

Tags: android, push-notification, air-native-extension

I have created a air native extension for android push notification, but when i run the application i am  getting the exception like:

Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION cat=[air.com.test.mobile] (has extras) } to air.com.test.mobile.debug requires air.com.test.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE due to sender com.google.android.gsf (uid 10019)

Manifest:

```
<android>
        <colorDepth>16bit</colorDepth>
        <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
   <manifest android:installLocation="auto">

       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>       
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>       
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

       <permission android:name="air.com.test.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
       <uses-permission android:name="air.com.test.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

       <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

       <application android:enabled="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="false">

        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
               <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
               <category android:name="air.com.test.mobile"/>
           </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
      <service android:name="com.adobe.sampleasextension.GCMIntentService" />
     <activity android:excludeFromRecents="false">
      <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
     </activity>
    </application>
   </manifest>

  ]]></manifestAdditions>
    </android>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, without seeing your manifest and based on the error you got, I suggest you add the following to your manifest :

```
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="air.com.test.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="air.com.test.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

EDIT:

I notice that the error also mentions `air.com.test.mobile.debug`. Which of them is the main package of your app? Perhaps you should change all the relevant places in your manifest that have `air.com.test.mobile` to `air.com.test.mobile.debug`.

Comment: Actually i have searched in my project i didn't find air.com.test.mobile.debug, but why this package is shown in the exception...

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your AndroidManifest file with  tag sibling and a child of  tag

```
<permission
        android:name="air.com.test.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="air.com.test.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

You have to create a permission first with your package name for push notification and then define that permission for your app, as shown above